# Problem with affiliations - Magnetic Resonance in Medicine manuscript

Tags: affiliation

I am preparing a manuscript to submit to MRM. They provided the Latex template but there is something odd. The author affiliations don't appear below the names in full line but they broke down in small lines. Every affiliation should be in single long line.

Here is the code

```
\author[1\authfn{1}]{Author One PhD}
\author[2\authfn{1}]{Author A.~Two MD}
\author[2\authfn{2}]{Author Three PhD}
\author[2]{Author B.~Four}

\contrib[\authfn{1}]{Equally contributing authors.}

% Include full affiliation details for all authors
\affil[1]{Department, Institution, City, State or Province, Postal Code, Country}
\affil[2]{Department, Institution, City, State or Province, Postal Code, Country}
```

I attached a photo how it looks like. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You should tell us which template you use and where is described that affiliations should appear in one long line. Could be that the journal changed this later. Have you asked the journal what to do? Seems to be an `wiley-article.cls`, right?

Comment: Yes it is a Wiley-article.

Answer (score 0):

The whole aim of a journal template is to hold blocks of information to be completely reset by the journal type setters. The way a template compiles is not always the way it will be published. In order to ensure fields are filled in in a uniform fashion they may be presented to the author in a variety of ways, then can be compiled in a different sequence (or suppressed). Possibly  typeset in yet another. As long as you are following the template exactly and don't change its structure you cant go wrong

From the WOL (Wiley Online Library) instructions

Reviewers receive manuscripts with no authors’ names listed to ensure unbiased, double-blinded review.

Instead of providing the authors’ names and affiliations in the main manuscript file, please do so on a separate title page file. Do not give names of authors or their affiliations in the main manuscript tex.